# Assignment of public IP on Oracle cloud instance

Tags: database, oracle, cloud, instance, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I created an instance in Oracle cloud. By mistake I forgot to assign public IP. I have to connect that instance with Putty so I need public IP for this instance.

Can anybody please suggest me how to assign the IP? Oracle docs is not helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20220331012421/https://www.mythics.com/about/blog/internet-access-methods-for-oci-compute-instances), it shows you how to add a public IP. Basically, you go the the VNIC, IP addresses part (on the left part of the screen there's a link to it), then choose edit in the menu (click on the  3 dots on the right), there you can choose to add an ephemeral public IP.